# How do you best help trees that have been damaged by severe freezing?

Tags: landscaping, freezing

In my home area, we had a very deep freeze about 2 weeks ago, at least, for this area. You can usually count on 1 hand the number of days it goes below 30 in a given year, and rarely does it go below 25 (Fahrenheit, BTW). It got down to almost 15 degrees for two nights, causing lots of damage...

In particular, I've noticed many of our plants have either died outright, or are looking to be in much worse shape than normal. What can I do to help make sure these plants don't die any further, and how can I tell if they are dead to the point where it's just worth cutting them entirely down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a lot to be done, damage done is , well , done. Best to just make sure they are fed and watered well, and in the fall you could trim any remaining dead wood though that's not necessary.
It's probably a bit early to determine if a tree will survive, let spring get here.

Trees are very self sufficient. Probably better than 80% of so called "tree care" is actually human care.

Comment: You are right jeff, let mother nature take it's course. Trees are usually quite hardy and may come back with little permanent damage.

Comment: I'm guessing if it's completely dead (IE, the branches just snap off), it's probably worth it to cut it down to the roots, even if it's only been a few weeks?